# iptables: how to block traceroute and allow ping?

Tags: linux, iptables, ping, icmp, traceroute

Hi first sorry for my english.
I'm trying to block traceroute --icmp (tracert) while still permitting the ping, using iptables. The problem is that when I permit the traffic of echo request, to allow the ping it allows traceroute too because traceroute uses echo requests.

To solve the problem I tried to block traceroute type of icmp before allowing the echo request, but it still does not work (type of icmp list https://inetdoc.net/guides/iptables-tutorial/icmptypes.html)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s9 -p icmp --icmp-type 30 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s9 -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Comment: Since, as you say, both use the same packet, this is going to be difficult. And there's also `tcptraceroute`, so even if you disallow ICMP packets, people can still trace. Recommendation: Give up trying to do something impossible. (And the important question of course is *why* are you trying to block traceroute. In case you think it'll improve security: it won't).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I drop all the packet at the end with iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP so tcptraceroute or traceroute with udp packets wont work
And also i dont think it will improrve security, i just need to be able to do it for school

Comment: If it's for school, it's like part of an exercise. Possibly you didn't mention important parts of the setup for this exercise, for example that this is an intermediate machine on the traceroute path? And which `pings` should suceed or fail? Because you **can** inspect the TTL field...

Comment: this exercice instruction is literally "pings must be allowed from lan to dmz, but not traceroute"  and i supposed that he meant icmp traceroute because we drop every other packet by default, but maybe they did not think themselve it is impossible. u are the third person to tell me it is impossible so..

Comment: I still get the feeling that you have not told us something important from the question. Post the question, and we can help you interpret it.

Comment: the document is in french :/ this part of the exercice is at the page 9, LAN->DMZ
https://mega.nz/file/ztolCKBS#y_tlt78JJxMfmWrMjhkxxIU_YMAqMiL4z29VDma-NIU